# bind rows on list of elements to list of data.frame

Tags: r

I have list of R elements and want to bind row all elements within the list.
Each row binds to data.frame based on the column class.
The actual data is quite large and each class has different columns. Here is sample

```
df_list <- list()
df_list[[1]] <- data.frame(Class = "x", y = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_list[[2]] <- data.frame(Class = "x", y = 2, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_list[[3]] <- data.frame(Class = "a", y = 3, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_list[[4]] <- data.frame(Class = "x", y = 4, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_list[[5]] <- data.frame(Class = "a", y = 5, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Desired output, looking this to be done programmatically

```
df_list_out <- list()

df_list_out[[1]] <- bind_rows(data.frame(Class = "x", y = 1, 
                                         stringsAsFactors = F),
                              data.frame(Class = "x", y = 2, 
                                          stringsAsFactors = F),
                              data.frame(Class = "x", y = 4, 
                                           stringsAsFactors = F))


df_list_out[[2]] <- bind_rows(data.frame(Class = "a", y = 3, 
                                           stringsAsFactors = F),
                              data.frame(Class = "a", y = 5, 
                                         stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to `rbind` the list of dataframes together and then `split`

```
temp <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
split(temp, temp$Class)

#$a
#  Class y
#3     a 3
#5     a 5

#$x
#  Class y
#1     x 1
#2     x 2
#4     x 4
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df_list %>% bind_rows() %>% group_split(Class)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, this works fine for smaller dataset. but when the data is get's bigger with each class has different columns there would huge columns >1500 to get with.

Comment: can we have condition to rind rows only when matching class

Comment: @Kg211 yes, but ultimately all the rows would be matched to atleast one class, isn't it ? It might be even slower to do that one-by-one for each class. Which part is slower? You can try `rbindlist(df_list)` from `data.table` to bind the list together which might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could `lapply()` over a vector of `"Class"`es and thus achieve that only one `"Class"` is processed at a time.

```
lapply(c("x", "a"), function(x) do.call(rbind, df_list[Map(`[[`, df_list, "Class") == x]))
# [[1]]
#   Class y
# 1     x 1
# 2     x 2
# 3     x 4
# 
# [[2]]
#   Class y
# 1     a 3
# 2     a 5
```